# Query on a Text view

Tags: android

I want to display the following output:

- Name    : Sangeetha
- Usn     : 4AL09IS025
- Address : Anderi West, Mubai.

Name and usn are displaying properly. But my Address is not displaying. What's the problem. Here's my code. Can anyone tell me what's the problem?`MainActivity.java` is the my main activity class.

```
package com.example.assignment3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btn;
    EditText etext1;
    EditText etext2;
    EditText etext3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        etext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_usn);
        etext3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_add);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        /** Called when the user clicks the Submit button */
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", etext1.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("usn", etext2.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("address", etext3.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

`Display.java` is my Display activity to receive the intent sent by Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.assignment3;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Details extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
    TextView text3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.new_name);
        text2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.new_usn);
        text3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.new_add);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        String Name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
        String Usn=intent.getStringExtra("usn");
        String Address=intent.getStringExtra("add");
        text1.setText(Name);
        text2.setText(Usn);
        text3.setText(Address); 

    }
}
```

Two layout files. First one is for the first activity(input) and 2nd one is for 2nd activity(output).`main_activity.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20.3dp"
        android:text="@string/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:text="@string/usn" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_usn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_usn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="@string/add" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edit_usn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/edit_add" />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="230dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/submit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

`activity_details.java`'s layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.assignment3.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20.3dp"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:text="@string/usn"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_usn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/new_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usn"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/add"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/new_usn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:singleLine="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are putting address as ("address") in extra and getting it as ("add") and that's the issue.... make both the same and see it working

Comment: Thank you...I didn't notice it at all..I have one more query..How to dynamically extend the no of lines of the textview?

Comment: getText() and then setText(previousText + yourNewText) it will always append new lines there, I guess what you mean by that!

Comment: I got it.. I have to put singleLine="false"

Comment: Now suppose I want to enter details of 5 students and display it in the next activity..How to store those details. Do I have to use an array or database is needed?

Answer (score 0):

try that ;
  Define same string for address

```
  Intent intent=getIntent();
            String Name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
            String Usn=intent.getStringExtra("usn");
            String Address=intent.getStringExtra("address");
            text1.setText(Name);
            text2.setText(Usn);
            text3.setText(Address);
```

Comment: Now suppose I want to enter details of 5 students and display it in the next activity..How to store those details. Do I have to use an array or database is needed?

Answer (score 0):

See lines `intent.putExtra("address", etext3.getText().toString());` and `String Address=intent.getStringExtra("add");` You need to change the `add` to `address` to make it work